# Why do I have weird vertical lines in my graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a simple line chart, but I have these weird vertical lines at every year (year is my x-axis). Any advice would be appreciated.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=hdb_table, aes(x=year, y=resale_price, color=flat_type)) +
          geom_line()
```

[image]

dput(head(hdb_table))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqmGh.png)

```
structure(list(year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), 
date = c("2015-01", "2015-01", "2015-01", "2015-01", "2015-01", 
"2015-01"), month_no = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01"
), month_name = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan"
), region = c("North-East", "North-East", "North-East", "North-East", 
"North-East", "North-East"), town = c("ANG MO KIO", "ANG MO KIO", 
"ANG MO KIO", "ANG MO KIO", "ANG MO KIO", "ANG MO KIO"), 
estate_type = c("Mature Estate", "Mature Estate", "Mature Estate", 
"Mature Estate", "Mature Estate", "Mature Estate"), flat_type = c("3 ROOM", 
"3 ROOM", "3 ROOM", "3 ROOM", "3 ROOM", "3 ROOM"), block = c("174", 
"541", "163", "446", "557", "603"), street_name = c("ANG MO KIO AVE 4", 
"ANG MO KIO AVE 10", "ANG MO KIO AVE 4", "ANG MO KIO AVE 10", 
"ANG MO KIO AVE 10", "ANG MO KIO AVE 5"), storey_range = c("07 TO 09", 
"01 TO 03", "01 TO 03", "01 TO 03", "07 TO 09", "07 TO 09"
), floor_area_sqm = c(60, 68, 69, 68, 68, 67), flat_model = c("Improved", 
"New Generation", "New Generation", "New Generation", "New Generation", 
"New Generation"), lease_commence_date = c(1986, 1981, 1980, 
1979, 1980, 1980), age = c(33, 38, 39, 40, 39, 39), remaining_lease = c(70, 
65, 64, 63, 64, 64), resale_price = c(255000, 275000, 285000, 
290000, 290000, 290000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),row.names= c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: There's also this error message: Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name, even though the console still plots the graph.

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(head(hdb_table))`?

Comment: hi deepseefan, i have added the dput(head(hdb_table)) output in the question

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(head(hdb_table))` as *text*, rather than image.

Comment: The patterns with the lines is typical of having set the wrong groups. If you'd add `group = some_variable` to the `aes()` call with some_variable being a variable that connects related observations it should be fine. Also, you could try formatting your year/month as a date and put that on the x-axis.

Comment: As @teunbrand suggested try `ggplot(data=hdb_table, aes(x=year, y=resale_price, group=flat_type)) + geom_line(aes(color=flat_type))`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you probably want is

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=hdb_table, aes(x=year, y=resale_price, color=flat_type, group = flat_type)) +
          geom_line()
```

The lines are joining up all points, rather than just within groups you've defined by color.