# Grouped Boxplots: geom_line results in unnecessary vertical lines & possible for 3 groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, boxplot

I want to group of boxplots in ggplot and simultaneously plot subject lines (between each condition group). I found solutions for doing this but only for two groupings, and also, an unecessary vertical line is added when I use geom_line.
*Background: I'm displaying results for different preprocessing steps of EEG data (Opticat, Taper), and all of this for two experimental conditions (Contrast).*

My original plan was to plot my data like this, and then add lines for subjects between the contrasts (green and orange boxplots) for all the groupings:

```
ggplot(table, 
       aes(x = Contrast2, 
           y = Frequency)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, aes(fill = factor(Contrast))) +
  facet_grid(~TaperType) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_line(aes(group = as.numeric(Subject)), color = "grey") + 
  ggtitle("Peak frequency by contrast condition")
```

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMNGc.png)

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783061/how-to-create-individual-lines-on-top-of-a-boxplot-with-multiple-groups) to add the lines and changed my code accordingly. Unfortunately, this was designed for two groupings, so I lost the additional grouping of "Opticat". Additionally, geom_line is applied not only accross but also in the contrast groups themselves (hence, the weird, grey vertical lines).

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3gLx.png)

Apparently, this might be because I did not specify the groups that the lines are applied to correctly ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728113/why-do-i-have-weird-vertical-lines-in-my-graph)), but I could not find a solution specific to my grouping constellation online.

Can anyone help, with either of these issues? Or both, at best?

Similar data can be generated like this:

```
OPTICAT = c(rep("Yes", 20), rep("No", 20))
Tapers = c(rep(c(rep("Singletaper", 10), rep("Multitaper", 10)),2))
Contr = c(rep(c(rep("low", 5), rep("high", 5)),4))
subject = c(rep(1:10, 4))

table <- data.frame(Subject = subject,
                    Opticat = OPTICAT,
                    TaperType = Tapers,
                    Contrast = Contr,
                    Frequency = runif(n = 40, min = 35, max = 70))
```

UPDATE

I tried specifying the `aes()` for each geom_ element, specifically, but this did not work:

```
ggplot(table) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, 
               aes(x = Opticat, 
                   y = Frequency,
                   fill = Contrast)) +  
  geom_line(color = "grey",
            aes(x = Contrast, 
                y = Frequency,
                group = as.numeric(Subject))) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(),
             size = 0.5,
             aes(x = Opticat, 
                 y = Frequency,
                 fill = Contrast,
                 group = Contrast)) +
  facet_grid(~TaperType) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Peak frequency by contrast condition")
```

[Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJKi7.png)

Comment: There are multiple observations for the same value of `Subject`, therefore the vertical lines. Perhaps you want to connect some measure of central tendency (median since these are boxplots?)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! This means that the vertical lines would disappear if I manage to add the grouping by "Opticat"... (Currently, there are multiple observations per Subject because both "Opticat" levels are concatenated.) 

Connecting the median doesn't do it, unfortunately – my goal is to show that the trend exists for the subjects, individually.

Comment: OK, I understand. Median would not show that. I think you need to remove the call to `aes()` in the `ggplot()` line and add the aesthetic for each geom individually to achieve this. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have an additional group "TaperType"  that should result in single boxplots containing only the unique 10 subjects, each. (So Contrast x Opticat x TaperType). Separating the `aes()` seems logical, how would I then specify `aes()` for `geom_line` so it is generated for all four contact condition comparisons? I tried smth and updated my question above with it, obviously it did not work ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer because it's too long for a comment, but I'm still trying to figure out the end goal. I think you need to go back to the data because you are trying to line up factors on the x axis that are not equal.

```
# First combine your grouping variables
t3 <- table %>% 
    mutate(groups=stringr::str_c(Opticat,Contrast))
  
  ggplot(t3) +
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, 
                 aes(x = groups, 
                     y = Frequency,
                     fill = Contrast))  +
    facet_grid(~TaperType)  +
    
    geom_line(color = "grey",
              aes(x = groups, 
                  y = Frequency,
                  group = as.numeric(Subject)))
```

[image]
From there you can update the x axis labels to be prettier.

Comment: I see! Since I want the lines to be across the contrast groups – from the red to the blue boxplots – your solution won't entirely work. But reformatting the data itself and then designing the x-axis according to my wishes is a great idea, I will do that. Thank you for being so helpful and enjoy the rest of your Sunday!

Comment: For my own curiosity I would appreciate seeing the solution when it come together, and also so that others may benefit if they are trying to create a similar figure. thanks.